# keep a page without reloading with request everytime

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have an java web application.

The home page is home.jsp .This page contains internally three jsp pages to load one is menu.jsp
main.jsp
footer.jsp

but when my application is loading every time it gets slower by menu.jsp as it contains all menus.
so i now need to load only main.jsp for every request so that it will become fast how can i do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX to asynchronously load some part of the page, but this is not the perfect solution, you need to check why the menu is slow, there is no excuse at all, solve your problems from the root not just paint over it!

Answer (score 0):

Put all menus in  with separate id and use id.innerHtml to write the the contents